# Read text from a text file to a string multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays

So I ran into a problem, I have a big text in a TXT file and I need to read it into a multidimensional array, without using LINQ.

Example:

> Hello(a11) my(a12) friend(a13).
>
> My(a21) name(a22) is(a23) David(a24),
>
> I(a31) am(a32) from(a33) England(a34).

What I have done so far:

```
String input = File.ReadAllText( "..\\..\\Analize.txt" ); 
int i = 0, j = 0; 
string[,] result = new string[10, 10]; 
foreach (var row in input.Split('\n')) 
{ 
    j = 0; 
    foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' ')) 
    {
        result[i, j] = string(col.Trim());
        j++; 
    } 
    i++; 
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: String input = File.ReadAllText( "..\\..\\Analize.txt" );

int i = 0, j = 0;
string[,] result = new string[10, 10];
foreach (var row in input.Split('\n'))
{
    j = 0;
    foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
    {
        result[i, j] = string(col.Trim());
        j++;
    }
    i++;
}

Comment: what error(s) are you getting with the above?

Comment: Your code works just fine, I don't see the problem that you ran into

Comment: Instead of `ReadAllText` you could use `ReadAllLines` or `ReadLines` so you don't have to do the line splitting.  Also instead of a 2D array which isn't suited for this because the data is jagged you should really use a `List<List<string>>` or at least a `List<string[]>`.  Otherwise you need to determine how many lines and which line has the most words before you can even create your 2D array.

Answer (score 0):

For the others who said his code "works just fine - true if his text is not dynamic size - but if there are more lines then 10, or more words then 10 in this particular example there will be an **IndexOutOfRangeException** !

If you do know anything about your file this is maybe the best for not running into exceptions:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:/temp/test.txt");

        int sizex = lines.Length;
        int sizey = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var splitline = lines[i].Split(' ');
            sizey = sizey < splitline.Length ? splitline.Length : sizey;
        }

        String[,] multillines = new string[sizex,sizey];

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            var splitline = lines[i].Split(' ');
            for (int j = 0; j < splitline.Length; j++)
            {
                multillines[i, j] = splitline[j];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it is works just fine. Not sure what your problem is. But if this:

> Hello(a11)

means that this word has to sit on position [1,1] then all you have to change is the counting start from `0` to `1`

```
int i = 1, j = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 String input ="Hello(a11) my(a12) friend(a13)";

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int[,] result = new int[10, 10];
    foreach (var row in input.Split(' '))
    {
        j = 0;
        foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
        {
            result[i, j] = int.Parse(col.Trim());
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result[3,9]);
```